# How to refresh console tab for cases automatically?

Tags: tab, console, refresh

This is my first time working on service cloud service, i am asked to refresh a primary tab (case) when a field in a child object change.

The case object has a related list for incoming and sent mails. an incoming mail arrive with a status "New" (it depends on your configuration you can change the status if you want to, but this is not the point).

when you click on an "New" incoming mail to reply, its status changes from "New" to "Read" and the console by default creates a new tab to display the record (the child record meaning  "EmailMessage" record) while keeping the Case tab unchanged. **and Here comes the point: the mail status in the Case tab (related list part) is still has a status "New" although it has been changed to "Read" and need to be refreshed to catch the change.**
[image]

Is there a way to refresh the case tab  automatically when i click on an incoming mail (and thus change the status) without the need to refresh it manually ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a Push Notifications feature in the Service Cloud Console that I was unaware of, there is even a [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/service_console_customize/units/service_console_customize_push) that covers this.

In order to enable it:

> Go to  User Name | Setup | Create (Under App Setup) | Apps
>
> Click edit next to the "Support Console" application
>
> Scroll to "Choose how Lists Refresh"  and select "Refresh List"
>
> Click the "Select objects and fields for notifications" link next to
>   "Choose Push Notifications"
>
> On the Push Notification page, Click the Edit Button.
>
> Select the "Cases" object in the available items and click the Add
>   button to move it to the Selected items.
>
> Next to the "Chose fields for push notifications" the Cases object
>   should now be shown.  Click the Edit link next to it to select the
>   fields that will trigger a refresh.
>
> On the "Select Cases List fields" Selects the fields you want to trigger a refresh
>   I created.
>
> Save

The documentation can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console2_push_notifications_view.htm&type=0)

Comment: Yes, i have already tried it and it does not work for the object EmailMessage, actually i am facing a lot of trouble with this object as neither triggers nor workflows seem to be working for it. for example a before Insert trigger does not fire for an insertion of object.

Comment: I am thinking  of using some Tool kit api for console

Comment: In the past i had vreated a vf page using the streaming api for my custom case console